# What else can I do to improve a site performance/completely eliminate render blocking resources?

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, render-blocking

I already used performance improvement plugins for wordpress like `WP-Rocket` to eliminate render blocking resources but it seems I'm still getting this problem no matter what configuration I set on the plugin. Is there any recommendation on another plugin or anything I can code?

[image]

I checked these options in the plugin:

- Defer JavaScript file upload.
- Optimize `CSS` upload.
- Minify `CSS` and `JavaScript`.

This apparently would do the trick but I don't see much difference in the metrics.

Comment: Expand the item. What are the render-blocking resources?

Answer (score 0):

To a large extent, the architecture of some plugins that you already have installed and start with the theme itself makes this delay happen. In this matter, there is no way to intervene. But you can check the question of the weight of the images and if after processing them on sites like [Tiny PNG](https://tinypng.com/) they will help to make the loading faster. Another solution would be to convert the images to the webp format, which is currently being well used and is lighter.